# Download attachment file from URL - JAVA

Tags: java, file, file-io, io, httpconnection

I am trying to download a file from a URL like below.
http://localhost/attachment.php?attachId=123
It was downloading as a PHP file instead of the attachment. I have tried like this.

```
url = new URL(sourceURL);
HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
httpcon.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76");
if(httpcon.getResponseCode()!=404){
    InputStream is = httpcon.getInputStream();
    Files.copy(is, Paths.get(destinationFile));
}
```

Comment: Here is a nice utility you can use, tested it and works fine http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/use-httpurlconnection-to-download-file-from-an-http-url

Comment: You described what you’re trying to do, but you forgot to describe the problem you’re having.  Are you getting a 404 response code?  If you’re getting an exception, edit your question and include the *entire stack trace.*